# How to output company name(and its index) which has minimum ID value from a JSONArray?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

There is `JSONArray` in my app which I get from an online API, each object in the `JSONArray` of `"production_companies"` represents a company and each one has name and id.

I want to extract company name which has minimum ID value.

in the following example the `Warner Bros. Pictures` `id` is the lowest `174`, so I want to output the name of `Warner Bros. Pictures`

```
"production_companies":[
    {"id":429,"name":"DC Comics"},
    {"id":923,"name":"Legendary Pictures"},
    {"id":9996,"name":"Syncopy"},
    {"id":118865,"name":"Isobel Griffiths"},
    {"id":9993,"name":"DC Entertainment"},
    {"id":174,"name":"Warner Bros. Pictures"}
]
```

With this method (huge thanks to @VeKe) `minId` outputs the id of the company which has minimum value among others , in the above emample it outputs `174`

```
    // Set Studio name
                try {
                    JSONArray c = jObject.getJSONArray("production_companies");
                    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
                    // Extract and Find minimum id
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < c.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = c.getJSONObject(i);
                        int idd = obj.getInt("id");
                        set.add(idd);
                    }
    
                    int minId = Collections.min(set);
                    int index = set.indexOf(minId); // getting the index of minId (NOT WORKING)
                    JSONObject jo = c.getJSONObject(index);
                    movie.setStudioname(jo.getString("name")); // outputting the name of the company which has minimum ID value
    
                } catch (JSONException e) {}
```

Now what I want is to get the index of `minId` , I tried `int index = set.indexOf(minId);`  but `indexOf` cannot be resolved.

**So what is the best method to get the index of `minId` ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
JSONArray c = jsonObj.getJSONArray("production_companies");
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
// Extract and Find minimum id
for (int i = 0 ; i < c.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject obj = c.getJSONObject(i);
     int id = obj.getString("id");
     set.add(id);
}

int minId = Collections.min(list);

// TODO get corresponsind name for minId
```

Comment: yes, I have kept part to get studio name as TODO for you to try

Comment: Hi, I tired to get the index of minId  using `int index = set.indexOf(minId);` but it is not working can you help with that if you have time , thanks

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lot of research I finally got what I wanted.

here is the final code ( modifying @VeKe 's answer a little bit) huge thanks to you.

```
// Set Studio name
            try {
                JSONArray c = jObject.getJSONArray("production_companies");
                ArrayList<Integer> set = new ArrayList<>();
                // Extract and Find minimum id
                for (int i = 0 ; i < c.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = c.getJSONObject(i);
                    int idd = obj.getInt("id");
                    set.add(idd);
                }
                // int minId = Collections.min(set);
                int index = set.indexOf(Collections.min(set));
                JSONObject jo = c.getJSONObject(index);
                movie.setStudioname(jo.getString("name"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {}
```